# UIDatePicker does not respect Daylight Savings Time

Tags: ios, swift, nscalendar, nsdatecomponents

I am trying to get the hour and minute values from a `UIDatePicker` for use in my server, but the value from the `UIDatePicker` is an hour off. My local timezone currently uses daylight savings time, so I'm assuming that the `UIDatePicker` is not respecting that.

Here is the code I'm using to convert the date provided by the `UIDatePicker` to its hour and minute values:

```
struct MyTimeSettings {

    var time: Date!

    init(from json: [String : Any]) {
        var calendar = Calendar.current
        calendar.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")!

        self.time = calendar.date(from: DateComponents(timeZone: TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")!, year: 0, month: 0, day: 0, hour: (json["Hour"] as! Int), minute: (json["Minute"] as! Int)))
    }

    init() {}

    func getJSON() -> [String : Any] {
        var calendar = Calendar.current
        calendar.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")!
        let components = calendar.dateComponents(in: TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")!, from: self.time)

        return [
            "Hour" : components.hour!,
            "Minute" : components.minute!
        ]
    }

    static func ==(lhs: MyTimeSettings, rhs: MyTimeSettings) -> Bool {
        return (lhs.time == rhs.time)
    }
}
```

To test it, I gave it a `Date` which evaluates to 10:15 PM EDT:

```
var settings = MyTimeSettings()
let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 1522894500)
settings.time = date

print(settings.getJSON()) // ["Hour": 2, "Minute": 15]
```

It also works properly with input JSON:

```
let json = ["Hour": 2, "Minute": 15]
print(MyTimeSettings(from: json).getJSON()) // ["Hour": 2, "Minute": 15]
```

My problem is that the same code does **not** work properly whilst getting the date from the `UIDatePicker`. I am using the [Eureka](https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka) library for displaying the `UIDatePicker` in a table view cell:

```
<<< TimePickerRow() { row in
    row.cell.datePicker.timeZone = TimeZone.current
    row.cell.datePicker.locale = Locale.current
    row.value = self.myTimeSettings.time
}.onChange({ (row) in
    self.myTimeSettings.time = row.value
})
```

I then set the time on the date picker to 10:15 PM (EDT), but I do not get 2:15 AM UTC:

```
print(myTimeSettings.getJSON()) // ["Hour": 3, "Minute": 12]
```

**Why is the date picker returning the wrong time?**

Comment: Before diving deeper into what might be wrong, does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532729/daylight-saving-time-and-time-zone-best-practices) help with any clarifications or advice?

Comment: @Aaron I'm not having trouble with time zones or date objects, I am trying to understand why the `UIDatePicker` is returning the wrong time when I have set the correct time zone.

Comment: What do you get if you simply `print(datePicker.date)`?

Comment: @DonMag I still get 3:12 AM: `-0001-11-30 03:12:00 +0000`

Comment: You are getting the correct date/time. UTC does not have "daylight saving time", so (for example) in U.S. Eastern time zone, `10:45 PM on March 10, 2018` is `3:45 AM on March 11 UTC`, and `10:45 PM on March 11, 2018` is `2:45 AM on March 12 UTC`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Apple's Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/Articles/dtTimeZones.html) you'll want to call this method:

> **Declaration**
>
> `func daylightSavingTimeOffset(for date: Date = default) -> TimeInterval`
>
> **Parameters**
>
> **date**
>
> The date to use for the calculation. The default value is the current
>   date.

Comment: Thanks for this! I was able to get it working -- see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Jake's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49653575/5569234), I was able to get the correct UTC time by adding the `daylightSavingTimeOffset` function to `MyTimeSettings`:

```
init(from json: [String : Any]) {
    var calendar = Calendar.current
    calendar.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")!

    self.enabled = json["Enabled"] as! Bool
    self.daysToNotify = (json["Interval"] as! [String]).map { SHNotificationIntervalType(rawValue: $0)! }
    self.time = calendar.date(from: DateComponents(timeZone: TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")!, year: 0, month: 0, day: 0, hour: (json["Hour"] as! Int), minute: (json["Minute"] as! Int)))
    if TimeZone.current.isDaylightSavingTime() {
        let offset = TimeZone.current.daylightSavingTimeOffset()
        self.time = self.time + offset
    }
}

init() {}

func getJSON() -> [String : Any] {
    var calendar = Calendar.current
    calendar.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")!

    var components: DateComponents
    if TimeZone.current.isDaylightSavingTime() {
        let offset = TimeZone.current.daylightSavingTimeOffset()
        components = calendar.dateComponents(in: TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")!, from: self.time - offset)
    } else {
        components = calendar.dateComponents(in: TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")!, from: self.time)
    }

    return [
        "Enabled" : self.enabled!,
        "Interval" : (self.daysToNotify.map { $0.rawValue }),
        "Hour" : components.hour!,
        "Minute" : components.minute!
    ]
}
```

Comment: Nicely done. When in doubt, I always go to the Apple Documentation